# My Windows Forms dosnt open after Renaming Form1

Tags: c#, forms, visual-studio-2015, rename

I just renamed my Form1 to Start(I Pressed F2 and typed in the new name)...
after i did that my Programm dosn't work anymore(No Form will open Up anymore)
What can I do that my Form will open up again?

Comment: show the form code and program.cs code

Comment: Did you rename your file inside Visual Studio or outside it?

Comment: I changed it inside the code
I found the reason...
I dont understand why but it works now 
I'll send the code later when im home

Answer (score 0):

Check if rename happened in Program.cs and designer file of the form